# Multiple catch statements with the same exception types

Tags: java, exception, types, try-catch

I've been looking all over for an answer to this and have yet to find one.

Basically I am trying to connect to a database server through a GUI. My boss wants to be able to enter all fields and then check to see if they are valid entries, then if there are any invalid entries, he wants me to turn the text red, indicating that the field is invalid. I have the try statement catch ClassNotFoundException and SQLException. Because there are multiple fields that need to be checked, I have tried to have a set of if statements to check the connection info. Here is the code below, I hope this makes sense...

```
    //The cancel boolean values in this code are used elsewhere to regulate the Threads
    try 
    {
                   //attempt connection here
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        String[] errors = new String[4]; //This will create a String array of the errors it catches
                                         //and will later get called into a method that displays
                                         //the messages in a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()
        if (e.getMessage().startsWith("The TCP/IP connection to the host"))
        {
            errors[0] = "SQL CONNECTION FAILED: Please check the server URL you entered to make sure it is correct.";
            cancel = true;
            mGUI.serverNameTextField.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }

        if (e.getMessage().startsWith("Login failed for user"))
        {
            errors[1] = "LOGIN FAILED: You do not have sufficient access to the server.";
            cancel = true;

        }
        if (e.getMessage().startsWith("Cannot open database"))
        {
            errors[2] = "SQL CONNECTION FAILED: Please check the database name you entered to make sure it is correct.";
            cancel = true;
            mGUI.dbNameTextField.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }

        mGUI.reportErrors(errors); //Method where it reports the String[] array of errors
                                   //However, the 'errors' parameter only returns one error
                                   //message at a time, which is the problem.
```

Thanks for any help!

*****EDIT***************
I found a solution, so hopefully this will help someone. I changed my if statements to add an AND argument checking for the specific error code. You find find the error code by either setting a break point and looking at the debug perspective, or you can do what I did and set a print statement to see the error code. Here is the print statement:

```
    System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
```

Here are my new for statements:

```
    try 
    {
        //attempt connection here
    } 
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        if (e instanceof SQLServerException && ((SQLServerException) e).getErrorCode() == 0)
        {
            //code here
        }
        else{
            //code here
        }
        System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getErrorCode()); //Here is the print statement to see the error code.
        if (e instanceof SQLServerException && ((SQLServerException) e).getErrorCode() == 4060)
        {
            //code here
        }else{
            //code here
        }
        if(cancel != true)
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Don't show this to your boss or you could get fired.

Comment: Relying on the text in the exceptions is a really bad idea. Just as an FYI.

Comment: That's why I made sure there is no company info. And the question is how do you try and check for multiple errors in the same try statement. It only lets me do one at a time, and I don't want to try and connect to the DB multiple times to check for errors. Slows the program down.

Comment: He was referring to the code rather than the question

Comment: Ok let me try and explain better...I only want to try and connect to the DB ONCE, and then in one try statement, check for the 2 exceptions above and then check for ALL FOUR of the possible errors I might get. Currently it only goes through the catch statement once, and when it finds any one of the errors, it breaks from the catch statement, failing to check for the rest of the errors.

Comment: mm you have a lot of poor design issues, but when you make this multi catch , only one exception per time will be throw, so if you e.getMessage startsWith(something) is true then the others won't be true cause they are different..

Comment: My bad design issues aside, could you please give a suggestion of how to get around this problem?

Comment: You're not going to be able to validate everything in one go. If the server's path is wrong, then you don't know what server you're trying to connect to, so it is impossible to determine whether or not a user or database name is valid until the path is corrected.

Comment: damo, thanks! That totally answers my question. I feel like I went full retard for not seeing this before...Oh well, I guess I will have to modify the program requirements since this is impossible to do.

Comment: It's not uncommon to present errors one at a time: user tries to connect --> invalid URL --> user fixes URL and tries to connect again --> insufficient privileges --> user changes login --> database not found --> etc. Especially when determining an error _depends_ on resolving previous errors first.

Comment: Yea that's the way it is currently, so I plan on just keeping it this way. Once again, I spend lots of time (unknowingly) trying to break laws of programming "physics"

Comment: You could go: if (e instanceof ClassNotFoundException) { ... } inside your catch block, but if doing it that way you might as well use a catch block for each exception type. Be aware that the text describing an exception could be specific to the library/version you are using, having conditions based on the exception text might tie you to a specific library version.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about that instead of using a text description?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I posted the fix above in my initial question.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways

1 having more than one catch with a common function

```
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    handleError(e);

}catch (SQLException e){
    handleError(e);
}
```

where handleError takes the exception as the argument.

You dont seem to do anything else so you can just combine them both into a single exception

```
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

which will catch everything but you have MUCH less control over the error handling.

Comment: he's already using the [pipe syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) to catch both `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException`...

Comment: Ah wasnt aware that was added in Java 7 - Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A general principle of exceptions is that they are handled at the point they are best abled to  be handled.

You seem to have very disparate exceptions and presumably a TCP exception thrown somewhere in the code is not the same as the SQLException thrown when connecting to a database (I might be wrong here since I don't know what the rest of the code looks like). So would not a set of exception handlers, one for each type make more sense. Also to reite from Bryan Roach, text disambiguation is not a good idea.

```
try {
...
} catch (java.net.SocketException e) {
 e[0] = "tcp error";
} catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
 e[1] = "sql exception happened";
}
```

Also your string array seems a bit risk, possibly a

```
ArrayList errors = new ArrayList();
errors.add("Some tcp error");
errors.add("Some db error");
```

and then for you error reporting

```
mGUI.reportErrors(errors.toArray())
```

would preserve your interface and not waste you having to allocate extra elements to the array and have empty entries. I don't know exactly what your question is, but you allude to the GUI not displaying multiple errors. Possibly there is a check which stops at the first empty element in an array. Say e[2] and e[4] is populated, it might stop when it iterates over the errors as e[3] is empty. I'm presuming again since I don't know what that code looks like

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above it sounds like what you want to do is have different logic for the various Exception types you are catching within a single catch block. If this is the case, you could go:

```
...
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    String[] errors = new String[4];
    if (e instanceof ClassNotFoundException) {
       //do something here
    }
    if (e instanceof SQLException) {
       //do something else here
    }
    ...etc
}
```

This should work, but it's probably just as easy to use multiple catch blocks as others have suggested:

```
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    handleError(e);
}catch (SQLException e){
    handleError(e);
}
```

I don't mean any offense, but the way the code handles exceptions might cause some headaches down the road. For example:

```
if (e.getMessage().startsWith("Cannot open database")) {
```

Here the code relies on the supporting library that throws the exception to use the same text description, but this description might change if you switch to another JVM version,  use a different database driver, etc. It might be safer to go by the exception type, rather than the exception description.

Comment: No offense taken. Thanks for the tip, I will change it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim! I found a work around and posted the results in my initial post.